# Factoring $y$ out of $y^2 + e^y$ possible?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, ordinary-differential-equations, factoring

I'm working on solving a separable first order differential equation where I get down to:

$$\frac12 y^2 + e^y = \frac12x^2 + e^{-x} + c$$

Is it possible to solve for $y$ here?  I can't think of a way to factor the left hand side.

Here's the original differential equation:

$$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{x-e^{-x}}{y + e^y}$$

Thanks!

Comment: Nope, not really. It's clear $y=-x$ is a solution for $C=0$. Perhaps you'd get more useful responses if you posted the original problem you're working on..

Comment: No, you cannot factor $y$ from the left hand side. What is the differential equation you were trying to solve?

Comment: Ok I posted the original problem.  Don't think I made a mistake elsewhere but possible.

Comment: Are there no initial conditions? Otherwise it looks like you'll have to be content with this implicit solution.

Comment: ok thanks, guess that's it.  @sdcvvc ah thanks for catching that sign

Comment: Hm, I don't think what I said was relevant. It seems anon is right and either you have a condition giving $C=0$, or the implicit solution is all what you can get...

Answer (score 2):

Apparently answered in comments:

> Nope, not really. It's clear $y=−x$ is a solution for $C=0$. Perhaps you'd
>   get more useful responses if you posted the original problem you're
>   working on.. – anon Apr 22 at 23:31
>
> No, you cannot factor $y$ from the left hand side. What is the
>   differential equation you were trying to solve? – Arturo Magidin Apr
>   22 at 23:31
>
> Ok I posted the original problem. Don't think I made a mistake
>   elsewhere but possible. – dacc Apr 22 at 23:34
>
> Are there no initial conditions? Otherwise it looks like you'll have
>   to be content with this implicit solution. – anon Apr 22 at 23:39
>
> ok thanks, guess that's it. @sdcvvc ah thanks for catching that sign –
>   dacc Apr 22 at 23:41
>
> Hm, I don't think what I said was relevant. It seems anon is right and
>   either you have a condition giving $C=0$, or the implicit solution is
>   all what you can get... – sdcvvc Apr 22 at 23:45